# Jest alternative for `assert.IfError(value)`

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Node's documentation of [`assert`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_iferror_value) module for `assert.ifError`

> Throws value if value is not **undefined** or **null**. This is useful when testing the error argument in callbacks. The stack trace contains all frames from the error passed to ifError() including the potential new frames for ifError() itself.

```js
assert.ifError(null);
// OK
assert.ifError(0);
// AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: 0
assert.ifError('error');
// AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: 'error'
assert.ifError(new Error());
// AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: Error
```

What is Jest alternative for `asser.IfError` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i figured it out.

### Solution 1. `expect.toContain` matcher.

```js
expect([undefined, null]).toContain(value);
```

### Solution 2. `jest.extended` module [`toBeNil`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#tobenil) method

#### installation

```sh
yarn add -D jest-extended
```

Use `.toBeNil` when checking a value is `null` or `undefined`.

```js
test('passes when value is null or undefined', () => {
  expect(null).toBeNil();
  expect(undefined).toBeNil();
  expect(true).not.toBeNil();
});
```